# JAVA print out the entire array while still within the for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is the "print schedule" part of my code:
I am not sure how to print out the entire array. Not just one part of the array.

```
if (input==3){
  int totalArray=IntStream.of(array).sum();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays You have elected:"+array[i]+
    +"array2 corresponding to those class: "+array2[i]+
    +"Sum of Array 2 is: "+totalArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, `course[position] == searchFor` needs to use `.equals` instead of `==` since Strings are objects.

Comment: What format would you like the array to be formatted into? Just commas?

Comment: use commas is fine. doesn't need to be anything fancy

And thank you. about the .equals. slip out of my mind lol

Comment: Remove the `while (input != 4)` from the program, and instead add a test case for `if (input == 4) System.exit(0);` It's keeping `i` from advancing beyond 0. Also, my answer doesn't quite match what you put in the code. You also need to only do `i++` if `input == 1`, and do `i--` if `input == 2`.

Comment: THANK YOU finally got everything to work like it should :D

Comment: Okay. That's great though! I'm glad you figured it out. Probably should select my answer as most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `String` variable by iterating over *each* array, and **then** output.

```
String arrayStr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    arrayStr += course[i];
    if (i + 1 != array.length)
        arrayStr += ", ";
}
```

You can use the same code for `array2`.

Comment: would this code go within the for loop or after the for loop?

Comment: This would go directly after the `int totalCredit=...` line.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. I forgot that `course.length` doesn't store the current size of the array, `i` does. Also, I changed my `i` to a `j` so that it wouldn't conflict.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to change `course[i]` over to `course[j]`. Fixed now.

Comment: when I run it the print shows this
Classes You have elected: ,
Credit corresponing to those class:  ,
total creadit is: 5

My input was: 2 classes each 5 credits worth. so the expected output should be 10

Comment: Your code is buggy in several places. [Here's my working code after reviewing yours](https://ideone.com/sTn8lp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toString` method from the static `Arrays` class:

```
Arrays.toString(course)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `StringBuilder` as follows:

```
private String toString(String[] courses){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String aCourse : courses) {
        builder.append(aCourse);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can also use `String.join("\t", courses)`

Or else, just iterate a build the concatenated string yourself:

```
String delim = "\t"
String result = courses[0];
for (int i = 1; i < courses.length; i++) {
    result = result + delim + result[i];
}
```

Comment: well that's the thing. This assignment does not allow method, and arrayslist 

Would have used both had it not limit me :(

Comment: `Arrays.toString` probably isn't in the format they want.

Comment: @duhNooby does the assignment allow you to just build the `String` before displaying the message? If so, boom! 

@4castle agreed, a `StringBuilder` is likely a better solution.

Comment: saddly... it also does not allow that...
any program that is build in within java IDE is not allow save for math, and JOptionPane... 

Pretty sure im not allow to use IntStream as well. but ill fix that later

Comment: The `String.join` method won't work for the integer array. See my answer

Comment: I'm really sorry about having to point so many things out, but that last attempt doesn't work if the `course` array is empty.